# Lightinject Equivalent of Ninject's WhenInjectedInto

Tags: light-inject

Does LightInject have an equivalent method of Ninject's `WhenInjectedInto()`? ([Ninject - Contextual Binding](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject/wiki/Contextual-Binding))

For example, I have two classes, let's say `MicrosoftOffice` and `LibreOffice`, that implement an interface `IOfficeSuite`. Two other classes, `Windows` and `Linux`,  implement another interface, `IOperatingSystem`. The latter interface depends on `IOfficeSuite`.

I'd like to decide which office suite to instantiate based on the context. So if LightInject is injecting an `IOfficeSuite` implementation into a `Windows` object, it should choose `MicrosoftOffice`; if it is a `Linux` object, it should inject an `LibreOffice` instance.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve it using `RegisterConstructorDependency`:

```
Container.RegisterConstructorDependency((factory, parameterInfo) => DecideImplementationByDeclaringType(factory, parameterInfo));

private static IInterface DecideImplementationByDeclaringType(IServiceFactory factory, ParameterInfo parameterInfo)
    {
        var declaringType = parameterInfo.Member.DeclaringType;

        if (declaringType == typeof (SomeClass))
        {
            return factory.GetInstance<IInterface >("OtherImplementation");
        }
        return factory.GetInstance<IInterface >("DefaultImplementation");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an example of what you are trying to do?